# C# WPF DynamicDataDisplay сохранение графиков

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется несколько графиков сделанных на базе D3 с разными именами (plotter1,plotter2...), каждый расположен на своей вкладке . 
Задача сохранить все графики.
У графика есть метод SaveScreenshot(string path), который сохраняет график по указанному пути. Однако этот метод сохраняет только то изображение графика, которое было последним показано на экране. Таким образом, если мы открыли окно и не пощелкали сами по вкладкам, сохранен будет только первый показанный график, вместо остальных будут черные квадраты.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста как правильно сохранить эти графики без необходимости пользователю щелкать по каждому графику.

Comment: а черные квадраты видимо потому что инициализация графиков не проводилась? низнаю как WPF конечно, но а вдруг

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё потому, что вы не отделили контент от представления.

Сохранять по уму нужно не скриншоты представления, а контент (то есть, данные, из которых этот график получается). Как и когда WPF покажет ваш график, вовсе не должно быть важно или интересно.

Если по каким-либо причинам нужно сохранять именно картинку, то всё равно нужно генерировать её на уровне модели, а не сохранять скриншот. У скриншота не то качество, разрешение, могут присутствовать лишние артефакты.

Делайте правильно, проблем не будет.

Comment: Построенный график обязательно нужно сохранить в виде изображения. Проблема заключается в том, что D3 не позволяет генерировать картинку на уровне модели.

Comment: @DmitryZheleznyakov: Хм. Это проблема. Может быть, тогда они недостаточно хороши для ваших целей? Библиотека должна уметь генерировать контент на уровне модели. Ну или давайте попробуем устроить workaround. Посмотрите в контролах, какой у них размер? Подпишитесь на Loaded и посмотрите, пришёл ли этот event.

Comment: Проблема, как выяснилось, сидит еще глубже. Библиотека категорически отказывается адекватно работать с сохранением при наличии больше 1-го графика на форме, независимо от их распределения. При попытке сохранить скриншот любого графика, кроме первого показавшегося, происходит выброс ArgumentException из недр библиотеки. В итоге, переделал форму под показ одновременно только одного графика, позже воспользуюсь другой библиотекой.

Comment: @DmitryZheleznyakov: Хм. А если рисовать график на невидимой форме? (Например, вообще в другом потоке?)

Comment: В общем-то так и сделал. В левом потоке создаю форму, загружаю, создаю на ней график, сохраняю график, закрываю форму. И так для каждого нужного графика.

Comment: @DmitryZheleznyakov: Угу, получается как бы использование view в качестве модели. Вот и хорошо.